Terraform for Vault - configuration does not work when using conditions in property
resource "vault_jwt_auth_backend_role" "ci_integration_role" {
  role_name = var.integration_name
  backend   = var.backend
  role_type = "jwt"

  user_claim        = "repository"
  bound_claims_type = var.match_on_subject ? "string" : "glob"

  bound_audiences = ["https://github.com/<org>"]

  bound_claims = var.match_on_subject ? null : {
    sub = var.subject
  }

  bound_subject = var.match_on_subject ? var.subject : null

  token_policies = [vault_policy.ci_integration_policy.name]

  token_ttl              = "300" # 5 minutes
  token_max_ttl          = "600" # 10 minutes
  token_explicit_max_ttl = "600" # 10 minutes
}

I define above configuration using Terraform.
When I use conditions in particular property, i.e.:
  bound_subject = var.match_on_subject ? var.subject : null

I can't authenticate to Vault using vault-actions in GitHub Actions:
Error: Response code 403 (Forbidden)
resource "vault_jwt_auth_backend_role" "ci_integration_role" {
  role_name = var.integration_name
  backend   = var.backend
  role_type = "jwt"

  user_claim        = "repository"
  bound_claims_type = var.match_on_subject ? "string" : "glob"

  bound_audiences = ["https://github.com/<org>"]

  bound_claims = var.match_on_subject ? null : {
    sub = var.subject
  }

  bound_subject = "repo:<org/repo>:ref:refs/heads/main"

  token_policies = [vault_policy.ci_integration_policy.name]

  token_ttl              = "300" # 5 minutes
  token_max_ttl          = "600" # 10 minutes
  token_explicit_max_ttl = "600" # 10 minutes
}

When I provide hardcoded value:
  bound_subject = "repo:<org/repo>:ref:refs/heads/main"

I'm able to run vault-actions and authenticate in Vault from GitHub Actions.
I defined many different configurations, anytime I used hardcoded approach - authentication worked.
Anybody experienced similar issue, or is there something in nature of Terraform that causes this behaviour?

Does the state show that it is configured properly in the first case?
